# Can an activity default constructor be overloaded with monodroid?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

In standard C#, I can overload the default constructor with something like

```
public class foo
{
  data bar;
  public foo(data bar)
  {
     this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can do this in monodroid? I'm trying to overload a default constructor in an activity (just to make it fun!).

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide an `Activity` constructor which takes parameters? Yes. Would it be at all helpful? No, because Activities are started through [Context.StartActivity()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Context.StartActivity(Android.Content.Intent)), which provides no mechanism to invoke a non-default constructor.

The "Android Way" to transfer data between Activities is to use the Intent "extras" mechanism, e.g. [Intent.PutExtra(string,string)](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Intent.PutExtra(System.String%2cSystem.String)) and [Intent.GetStringExtra(string)](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Intent.GetStringExtra(System.String)), which introduces it's own set of problems:

1. Intents are also an IPC mechanism (as an Activity may actually reside in another process -- this is by design), so you're restricted to types which can be marshaled across process boundaries.
2. `String`s, `int`s, and other builtin types are supported, but aren't exactly "high level" objects.
3. "Higher level" objects are supported through the [android.os.Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface, but (a) has a "marshal by value" semantic, so isn't useful for sharing read+write data between activities, and (b) [Mono for Android doesn't currently support implementing this interface](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/limitations).

So how do you share data between Activities? By punting.

- Place the data onto an [Application](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T:Android.App.Application) subclass. This will be accessible via the [Context.ApplicationContext](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P:Android.Content.Context.ApplicationContext) property, and can store process-global state.
- Use some other `public static` field within your process to contain the shared information.
- Provide a [ContentProvider](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Content.ContentProvider) implementation which will store and provide the desired data when prompted.
- Sqlite?
- etc.

Comment: Thanks - that's useful. Are there any code examples available for these methods. I thought of making the class I'm passing about as being Serializable and passing that though the PutExtra call but there doesn't seem to be a serializable overload....

Answer (score 0):

You don't implement constructors in activities in Android. Please perform this sort of initialization in `onCreate()`, after calling `super.onCreate()`.

(my apologies for the Java syntax -- I don't speak C#)